# what to do if user types in same social account email and password instead of Single Sign-on?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, google-signin, apple-sign-in

I'm a rookie exploring sign in options for my website. It seems popular to use google, facebook, apple SSO service to login in third party website. My question is if one user SSO using say, google account for the first time, next time instead of choosing google to SSO he types in the same gmail and password on the website login page. The website knows the is an existing login email but how to verify the password? Does google SSO service allow third party website to pass the gmail account and password to verify? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the user logs in they sign in with their google account.

What will happen is that your system will store their internal google user id, as well as their email address.  Both of these are returned to you.

If they then signin with facebook the same should happen you get an internal facebook user id and their email.

Your system then should do something called account linking. It will link these two user accounts via the email address.

If they then chose to create a new account on your site directly with the same email again they get linked.

This was just a quick example you may want to do a bit of research on account linking.

Comment: Thanks. To my question, does that mean since no password was stored in my website for SSO account, if user tries to use the gmail to login on my website directly, I should prompt the user to set the password for my website first?

Comment: yes if the user tries to create an account on your website directly then you should store an email address and a password for them.   If its the same email as an already excising password used for a social login then you can just link the accounts.    TBH what i normally do is when they create a social login if i dont have that email then i automatically create a standard user on my site and prompt them to set a password